# Cassandra migration from one on premises provider to another provider. Consistency and integrity check of data

Tags: cassandra, database-migration, data-migration, cassandra-3.0

We have on premises cassandra cluster, as we are changing service providers, the data should be migrated to new clusters offline via backup files. Do we have any utility in cassandra to verify if data is restored properly via checksums? somewhat like in mysql [checksum](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/checksum-table.html). I have checked Datastax [docs](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/3.0/cassandra/tools/toolsVerify.html#).

What is the best possible way to verify the data integrity and consistency?

Comment: You can move the data folder to the new node and startup the node with same config file, and the data comes up as how it is in the old node